# Use a formula(contaning calculation involving column names) present in one of the columns of dataframe to perform the actual calculation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,3,5,7],'col2':[2,4,6,8],'col3':['(col1*(1+col2))*col1','col1+col2','col1/col2','col1-col2']})
df
  col1  col2    col3
0   1   2   (col1*(1+col2))*col1
1   3   4   col1+col2
2   5   6   col1/col2
3   7   8   col1-col2
```

Now what I want to do is to actually perform the calculations in the col3 and create a new column col4 which contains the values, so the output would look something like:

```
  col1  col2    col3             col4
0   1   2   (col1*(1+col2))*col1  3  
1   3   4   col1+col2             7
2   5   6   col1/col2            .83
3   7   8   col1 - col2          -1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`numexpr`](https://github.com/pydata/numexpr) (probably already installed):

```
import numexpr

evaluate = lambda x: pd.Series(numexpr.evaluate(x.name, x), x.index)
df['col4'] = df.groupby('col3', group_keys=False).apply(evaluate).astype(float)
```

For 400 records:

```
# @jezrael
%timeit df.groupby('col3', group_keys=False).apply(lambda x: x.eval(x.col3.iat[0]))
5.76 ms ± 181 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

# @corralien
%timeit df.groupby('col3', group_keys=False).apply(evaluate).astype(float)
1.22 ms ± 2.39 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

---

You can use [`df.eval`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eval.html) and [`np.diag`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.diag.html) to get expected values:

```
df['col4'] = np.diag(df.eval(df['col3']))
print(df)

# Output
   col1  col2                  col3      col4
0     1     2  (col1*(1+col2))*col1       3.0
1     3     4             col1+col2       7.0
2     5     6             col1/col2  0.833333
3     7     8             col1-col2      -1.0
```

If your dataframe contains more than 100 rows, you should use the following code because `pd.eval` has a [known bug](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16289#issuecomment-299994205):

```
df['col4'] = np.concatenate([np.diag(df1.eval(df1['col3'])).astype(float)
                             for df1 in np.array_split(df, 1 + len(df) // 100)])
```

Comment: I test with larger df and got error - `df = pd.concat([df] * 100, ignore_index=True)`

Comment: You know it's a [bug](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16289#issuecomment-299994205) because you already found [it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64801320/15239951). Thanks.........

Comment: It was ironic... I think you really don't have a very good mind. You are too competitive for me. Why let me search when you know? What's the goal? That your answer is accepted and not mine?

Comment: I am not ironic, sorry if it sound like it.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.eval`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eval.html) per groups with same values in `col3` column and pass first value of `col3`:

```
df['col4'] = df.groupby('col3', group_keys=False).apply(lambda x: x.eval(x.col3.iat[0]))

print (df)
   col1  col2                  col3      col4
0     1     2  (col1*(1+col2))*col1  3.000000
1     3     4             col1+col2  7.000000
2     5     6             col1/col2  0.833333
3     7     8             col1-col2 -1.000000
```